# Prevent files in src/main/app being embedded in the Mule .zip

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

It's mostly in the title; I'm trying to embed a SPA webapplication (some html and js) in src/main/app and let Mule serve it trough a static handler.

Though I'd only like the minified javascript to be served which I place (using webpack) in the /src/main/app/webapp/build directory. I'd like to exclude the /src/main/app/webapp/project directory from the Mule zip after a Maven 'package'. The /project/ directory has thousands of files for the webapp potentially.

I think I tried all of the Maven guides to exclude files out there but can't get it to work:

```
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/app</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>webapp/project/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to move those files from /src/main/app to /src/main/resources. As the src/main/app folder is going to be loaded in the classpath when using the maven plugin to package your mule app

Comment: Seems like an idea, but how would I point the static file handler in the Mule flow to the src/main/resources? I only know of the ${app.home} variable, is there one for the resources folder?

Comment: Ah, after reading some more, I now understand ${app.home} better. It's not /src/main/app in design time, (although running a project from anypoint makes you think that it is), it's the root of the project during runtime after the Maven 'mule' goal is done building. I've placed it now into main resources and then it seems to follow the include/exclude instructions better. It's still placed in 'classes' but that's a minor problem I guess.

Comment: Glad to know you can move forward :)